# Creating a server with fixed IP that can be freely moved among networks

Tags: domain-name-system, routing, subnet, ip-address

Given a public /24 prefix, announced via BGP, 192.0.2.0/24. I have split this prefix into various smaller networks. I would like to use 1-2 servers for the DNS server (forward and reverse) which needs a static IP. Since this IP needs to go as NS record into the parent zone, changing IP is not simple (and requires support of the admin of 2.0.192.in-addr.arpa).

The various networks are connected to each other via p2p links/tunnels and OSPF. One such network is 192.0.2.208/28 and I would like to use 192.0.2.212 as DNS server. The DNS server will be a virtual machine and I would like to have the flexibility to move it to another network at a different location, say 192.0.2.234 in 192.0.2.232/29. Normally this requires not only changing the IP but also coordinating with the owner of 2.0.192.in-addr.arpa on the NS record update.

I was thinking of picking a /32 address from the prefix, say 192.0.2.255/32. This address could then be assigned to a dummy device or as a second IP. But unless the DNS server becomes a router (and/or runs OSPF too) I need to deal with static routing which sounds like a hassle too.

What is the best solution for this scenario? Nearly any other service can be addresses via DNS, so the IP itself is not as critical. But for a DNS server it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred method for doing such things is running your DNS server on Virtual IP supported by *VRRP* (*keepalived*) or *CARP* (*ucarp*). However, this will work within common broadcast domain only.

If you don't want to deal with OSPF or static routing on a server but still want it to roam between subnets you can use some sort of tunneling between the server and border router, i.e. use L2TP and use /32 assigned to tun0 as DNS server address.